# Output BeautifulSoup website elements as a list

Tags: arrays, list, beautifulsoup

I need to 
1.) output and store a LIST of websites using BeautifulSoup the package. My results are too long:
Official site: www.vigeland.museum.no/en/vigeland-park.
2.) How can I translate the type 'bs4.element.Tag' to list (basically)

At best, I only need
 'www.vigeland.museum.no'    etc

```
import requests # library to handle requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
#
r = requests.get('https://www.planetware.com/tourist-attractions-/oslo-n- 
osl-oslo.htm')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print('request successful')
#
web_site=soup.find_all('div', class_="web")
for web in web_site:
    print(web.text)
    type(web)


### My RESULT ###
Official site: www.vigeland.museum.no/en/vigeland-park
Official site: www.khm.uio.no/english/visit-us/viking-ship-museum/
Official site: www.nasjonalmuseet.no/en/
Official site: http://munchmuseet.no/en
Official site: http://www.kongehuset.no/seksjon.html?tid=28697
Official site: www.khm.uio.no/english
Official site: http://frammuseum.no
Official site: www.skiforeningen.no/en/holmenkollen
Official site: https://www.oslo.kommune.no/politikk-og-a 
dministrasjon/radhuset/visit-the-oslo-city-hall/
Official site: www.akerbrygge.no/english
Official site: www.nhm.uio.no/english/
Official site: http://operaen.no/en/

bs4.element.Tag
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A tidier and more efficient way would be to use class and [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) to get the child `a` tag. You then get exactly the right number and no need for string tidying.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
r = requests.get('https://www.planetware.com/tourist-attractions-/oslo-n-osl-oslo.htm')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
links = [item['href'] for item in soup.select('.web > a')]
```

Answer (score 0):

`Split()` the text value and then `strip()` white spaces and store only last value of string.

```
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
r = requests.get('https://www.planetware.com/tourist-attractions-/oslo-n-osl-oslo.htm')
soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
print('request successful')
web_site=soup.find_all('div', class_="web")
websiteofficial=[web.text.split('Official site:')[1].strip() for web in web_site]
print(websiteofficial)
```

### Output:

```
['www.vigeland.museum.no/en/vigeland-park', 'www.khm.uio.no/english/visit-us/viking-ship-museum/', 'www.nasjonalmuseet.no/en/', 'http://munchmuseet.no/en', 'http://www.kongehuset.no/seksjon.html?tid=28697', 'www.khm.uio.no/english', 'http://frammuseum.no', 'www.skiforeningen.no/en/holmenkollen', 'https://www.oslo.kommune.no/politikk-og-administrasjon/radhuset/visit-the-oslo-city-hall/', 'www.akerbrygge.no/english', 'www.nhm.uio.no/english/', 'http://operaen.no/en/']
```

Comment: Your answer was just perfect. I had 2 missing websites that should be at Number 2 and Number 9.  I simply added them using: #websiteofficial.insert(1, 'wikipedia.org/wiki/Akershus_Fortress')
#websiteofficial.insert(9, 'wikipedia.org/wiki/Oslo_Cathedral')